# No output when write on file

Tags: c++

file output is empty and this problem happen with any code 
Note : the direction file is true .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
    while (myfile.is_open()) {
        myfile << "This is a line.\n";
        myfile << "This is another line.\n";
        myfile.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to do 
std::fstream myfile( "example.txt", std::ios_base::out);

Comment: what if the file could not be opened? In that case your code does nothing...

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong. Except the `while` should be an `if`. You can then add an `else` and print a message if the file could not be opened. Or, maybe you are looking at the wrong folder. Delete "example.txt" then run the program again.

Comment: Try an absolute path for the file name, such as `/tmp/example.txt` or `c:\\example.txt`. If you're running in an IDE, it's frequently the case that you're running in a different directory than you *think* you are.

Answer (score -2):

first make sure that the file is opened.

then you can try this

```
ofstream myfile ("example.txt" , ios::out);
```

Comment: Not sure that will do any good? The default value for the second parameter is already `out`.